# Sort multi-bucket aggregation by source fields inside inner multi-bucket aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

***TL;DR:** Using an inner multi-bucket aggregation (`top_hits` with `size: 1`) inside an outer multi-bucket aggregation, is it possible to sort the buckets of the outer aggregation by the data in the inner buckets?*

---

I have the following index mappings

```
{
  "parent": {
    "properties": {
      "children": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "child_id": { "type": "keyword" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and each child (in data) has also the properties `last_modified: Date` and `other_property: String`.

I need to fetch a list of children (of all the parents but without the parents), but only the one with the latest `last_modified` per each `child_id`. Then I need to sort and paginate those results to return manageable amounts of data.

I'm able to get the data and paginate over it with a combination of `nested`, `terms`, `top_hits`, and `bucket_sort` aggregations (and also get the total count with `cardinality`)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "children": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "children"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "totalCount": {
                "cardinality": {
                    "field": "children.child_id"
                }
            },
            "oneChildPerId": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "children.child_id",
                    "order": { "_term": "asc" },
                    "size": 1000000
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "lastModified": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "_source": [
                                "children.other_property"
                            ],
                            "sort": {
                                "children.last_modified": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            },
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    },
                    "paginate": {
                        "bucket_sort": {
                            "from": 36,
                            "size": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

but after more than a solid day of going through the docs and experimenting, I seem to be no closer to figuring out, how to sort the buckets of my `oneChildPerId` aggregation by the `other_property` of that single child retrieved by `lastModified` aggregation.

**Is there a way to sort a multi-bucket aggregation by results in a nested multi-bucket aggregation?**

---

What I've tried:

- I thought I could use `bucket_sort` for that too, but apparently its `sort` can only be used with paths containing other single-bucket aggregations and ending in a metic one.
- I've tried to find a way to somehow transform the 1-result multi-bucket of `lastModified` into a single-bucket, but haven't found any.

---

*I'm using ElasticSearch 6.8.6 (the `bucket_sort` and similar tools weren't available in ES 5.x and older).*

Comment: Interesting question. Is there any way you could provide some example docs, especially ones sufficient to clearly demonstrate that the sorting is working correctly? Maybe using https://gist.github.com/ . An expected result (i.e. take your current response and reorder by hand as you'd ideally like it to be) would be fantastic as well, but optional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed a `terms` aggregation with a nested `top_hits`, and want to sort by a specific field inside the nested aggregation.

Not sure how performant my solution is, but the desired behaviour can be achieved with a single-value metric aggregation on the same level as the `top_hits`. Then you can sort by this new aggregation in the `terms` aggregation with the `order` field.

Here an example:

```
POST books/_doc 
{ "genre": "action", "title": "bookA", "pages": 200 }
POST books/_doc 
{ "genre": "action", "title": "bookB", "pages": 35 }
POST books/_doc 
{ "genre": "action", "title": "bookC", "pages": 170 }
POST books/_doc 
{ "genre": "comedy", "title": "bookD", "pages": 80 }
POST books/_doc 
{ "genre": "comedy", "title": "bookE", "pages": 90 }

GET books/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_genre": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "genre.keyword",
        "order": {"max_pages": "asc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_book": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"pages": {"order": "desc"}}]
          }
        },
        "max_pages": {"max": {"field": "pages"}}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`by_genre` has the `order` field which sorts by a sub aggregation called `max_pages`. `max_pages` has only been added for this purpose. It creates a single-value metric by which the order is able to sort by.

Query above returns (I've shortened the output for clarity):

```
{ "genre" : "comedy", "title" : "bookE", "pages" : 90 }
{ "genre" : "action", "title" : "bookA", "pages" : 200 }
```

If you change `"order": {"max_pages": "asc"}` to `"order": {"max_pages": "desc"}`, the output becomes:

```
{ "genre" : "action", "title" : "bookA", "pages" : 200 }
{ "genre" : "comedy", "title" : "bookE", "pages" : 90 }
```

The type of the `max_pages` aggregation can be changed as needed , as long as it is a single-value metic aggregation (e.g. sum, avg, etc)